# Styling Links - Overriding Existing CSS in WordPress Theme

Tags: css

I use a WordPress theme with existing styles for links. I am trying to figure out how I can create 4 different classes of link styling.

I noticed in another website they used Span class="link-text" as way to style different types of links within their site and I'm looking for some direction on how I would set up that class like that in my custom CSS page.

I set up in my custom CSS file:

```
.link-text {
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: underline;
}
```

And used

```
<a href="mylink" class="link-text">text</a>
```

But it didn't work. What did I do wrong? It appears it's still picking up the CSS anchor tag styling, which is what I'm trying to get away from.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `!important` and/or specify the element more to override other CSS. For example, `font-weight: bold !important;`

Comment: Thank you, working as expected. I think I also had browser caching issue - it worked fine in Firefox and only finally worked correctly after I cleared cache in Chrome. It's always sumpthin'.

Answer (score 0):

Add another stylesheet of your own in functions.php which has higher priority than the theme's stylesheet and write your own css there.

Or if you are doing it in the theme editor or by any other custom CSS plugin,

then simply use '!important' for the property of target class.

Eg:

```
.any-class{
 any-property:any-value!important;
}
```